# arguments for proc in ruby

Tags: ruby, arguments, proc

I am trying to run this code. I am trying to pass arguments into inner proc but my code does not run because of this. What am I doing wrong?

```
def log (descriptionOfProc,proc)
  puts "I have started proc #{descriptionOfProc}"
  puts "#{descriptionOfProc} is finished, returning #{proc.call}"
end

inner=Proc.new do |x,y|
  x+y
end

middle=Proc.new do |x| 
  log("inner", inner[1, 2])
  "check2"
end

outer=Proc.new do |x| 
  log("middle", middle)
  "check3"
end

puts log("outer", outer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `inner[1,2]` inside `middle` proc, you're actually executing the function which will return a value `3` then the argument to `log` will be `"inner", 3` and since 3 does not respond to `call` your script fails.

If you want to fix your script your middle proc should look something like this

```
middle=Proc.new do |x| 
  log("inner", -> { inner[1, 2] })
  "check2"
end
```

The reason your code was not working was because you were executing the function `inner` with `[]`. You can execute a block in ruby in different ways `.call`, `.yield`, `.()`, `[]`. As you can see, you were passing in the result of inner instead of the proc itself. By wrapping the call to `inner[1,2]` inside another block to be executed later inside `log` by doing `proc.call`, you delayed inner's execution.

Comment: thank you so much! this is exacted what i needed and my code runs. Question, what is the name of this notation and how can I learn more about it? What does ->{} does?

Comment: thanks! how come that it does not execute the function when written between -> {} but executes it if I omit ->{}

Comment: @SimpleLime technically that is a `lambda` which is a particular kind of `Proc`. `lambda`s act more like an anonymous method than a traditional `Proc` created via `Proc.new`